# GWT 2.2.0 PopupPanel autoHide on TOUCH Events

Tags: gwt, touch, mobile-safari

PopupPanel is a class within GWT written (akhem) a long time ago (which is why it sucks so much) that allows for showing popups with content. One of the options is autoHide where if there's a certain event outside of the popup it closes the popup. It works well on anything EXCEPT Safari Mobil (SM). Reason is SM doesn't fire click events on touch. It fires touch events. PopupPanel is hard coded to look for ClickEvents.

Specifically, the code says:

```
case Event.ONMOUSEDOWN:
   ...
   if (!eventTargetsPopupOrPartner && autoHide) {
      hide(true);
   ...
```

Obviously this isn't complete and it should also include Event.ONTOUCHSTART

Problem is, all the methods and fields are private so I cannot add this functionality. That's a big boo-boo on the part of GWT team but not really a concern since I could just make my own class and copy contents of PopupPanel. The big problem is that nativeEventPreview doesn't capture Touch Events!

I tried adding the following to Event Preview the following:

```
private static NativePreviewHandler nativePreviewHandler = new NativePreviewHandler() {
    public void onPreviewNativeEvent(NativePreviewEvent event) {
        Event nativeEvent = Event.as(event.getNativeEvent());
        switch (nativeEvent.getTypeInt()) {         
        case Event.ONTOUCHSTART:        
        case Event.ONMOUSEDOWN:
            EventTarget target = nativeEvent.getEventTarget();
            if (!Element.is(target) || !popup.getElement().isOrHasChild(Element.as(target))) {                  
                popup.hide();
            } break;
        }       
            }
};
```

Where 'popup' is the PopupPanel I'm trying to get to close on outside touch events. 
Sad thing is it works for mouse down when testing in any other browser on Earth, but not on iPad.

Another thing I tried was adding a TouchStartHandler to the glass of the PopupPanel (the gray looking thing behind it). I war hoping that I could catch the touch events that way, but I was unable to get events to fire on glass since it's attached to DOM in some funny way. My code:

```
private static class ProperPopupPanel extends PopupPanel {

    public ProperPopupPanel() {
        super();            
}          

    void setHideOnGlassTouch() {
        setGlassEnabled(true);

        TouchableLabeThatDoesntCrashOnWrap glass = new TouchableLabeThatDoesntCrashOnWrap(getGlassElement());
        glass.addTouchStartHandler(new TouchStartHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onTouchStart(TouchStartEvent event) {                   
                hide();                 
            }

        });
        glass.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                hide();                     
            }               
        });
    }       

    private class TouchableLabeThatDoesntCrashOnWrap extends Label {
        public TouchableLabeThatDoesntCrashOnWrap(Element element) {
            super(element);
            super.onAttach();
        }
    }
}
```

In my mind this should work, but it doesn't. I don't know why. Any ideas or suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not enough GWT users here... well I made my own class that adds touch handlers through JSNI ...

```
/**
 * Overwrite of the usual PopupPanel with a modification that this one
 * works well on touch-enabled browsers.
 * @author McTrafik
 */
public class ProperPopupPanel extends PopupPanel {

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////////// OVERRIDES //////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public ProperPopupPanel() {
        super();
        setTouchListener();
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        super.hide();
        removeTouchListener();

    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        super.show();
        addTouchListener();
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////////// NANDLERS ///////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    protected JavaScriptObject touchHandler;

    /**
     * Handle a touch event that happened while the popup is open.
     * @param event - The event to handle
     */
    protected void handleTouchEvent(Event event) {
        // Check to see if the events should be firing in the first place.
        if (!isShowing()) {
            removeTouchListener();
            return;
        }
        // Check if the event happened within the popup
        EventTarget target = event.getEventTarget();
        if (!Element.is(target) || !getElement().isOrHasChild(Element.as(target))) {
            // Stop event if the popup is modal
            if (isModal()) event.preventDefault();
            // Close the popup if the event happened outside
            if (isAutoHideEnabled()) {
                hide(true);
                removeTouchListener();
            }
        }
    };


    /**
     * Create a touchHandler that knows how to point to this instance.
     * Without it there's a cast exception that happens.
     */
    protected native void setTouchListener() /*-{
        var caller = this;
        this.@[package].ProperPopupPanel::touchHandler = function(event) {
            caller.@[package].ProperPopupPanel::handleTouchEvent(Lcom/google/gwt/user/client/Event;)(event);
        }
    }-*/;


    /**
     * Add a touch listener that will listen to touch events.
     */
    protected native void addTouchListener() /*-{
        $doc.addEventListener(
            "touchstart", 
            this.@[package].ProperPopupPanel::touchHandler, 
            true
        );
        $doc.addEventListener(
            "MozTouchDown", 
            this.@[package].ProperPopupPanel::touchHandler, 
            true
        ); 
    }-*/;


    /**
     * Remove the touch listeners
     */
    protected native void removeTouchListener() /*-{
         $doc.removeEventListener(
             "touchstart", 
             this.@[package].ProperPopupPanel::touchHandler, 
             true
         );
         $doc.removeEventListener(
             "MozTouchDown",
             this.@[package].ProperPopupPanel::touchHandler, 
             true
         );
    }-*/;


}
```